# $m(\{x\in K^c;d(x, K) < \varepsilon\}) =O(\varepsilon^{\alpha})$

Tags: functions, lebesgue-measure

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a nonempty compact set, and

$f(\varepsilon)= m(\{x\in K^c;d(x, K) < \varepsilon\})$, where

$m$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $\displaystyle d(x, K)=\inf_{y\in K}|x-y|$.

Does the following hold?

There is a $\delta>0, C>0, \alpha>0$ such that $f(\varepsilon)\leq C\varepsilon^{\alpha}$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\delta$.